# Resizing frame from video to fit ImageView

Tags: android

I am trying to duplicate the presentation method of Google's Photos app when playing videos. Namely, a frame from the video is first presented as a `Bitmap`, and then on click of the play button, the video re-sizes to full-screen and plays.

Here is how I am getting a frame from the video to display as a `Bitmap`:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.fragmentImageView);
retriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
mImageView.setImageBitmap(retriever.getFrameAtTime());
```

Here is the layout I am using to display the `ImageView`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentImageView"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black">
    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I also use this layout to display pictures taken with the camera. When it is displaying a camera picture, this layout looks identical to the Photos app: the image takes up the entire width of the screen, and there are black bars on the top and bottom.

However, when I use this layout to display the video frame, the image takes up the entire height of the screen, and there is a white bar running down the right side.

**How can I scale the `Bitmap` returned by `getFrameAtTime()` to fit the desired layout, without distorting it?**

I appreciate any advice or examples. Thank you!